# Customer and admin user architecture using MEAN

Tags: architecture, mean-stack, mean

I am currently in the process of developing a web app using the MEAN stack. There needs to be a customer facing site and admin site for staff. It will have an api which can be used by both sides which will be fine.

But in regards to the structure of the project should i have a different project for customer and another for the admin? Or should i integrate into one project as i need to have only one domain which will have a customer login area and an admin.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This depends a bit on your project scope. My team and I are currently working on a MEAN project and are specifically implementing it as a single project. The idea is to maximize code reuse, readability, and consistency across the app. Splintering the app across projects increases the likely-hood of violating the above, as well as increasing risk in regards to masking compatibility bugs until launch both projects together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was my thinking as well as code can be reused. How have you split the customer and admin side of it? (If you guys are actually doing that?) Also did you set mean from scratch or use a scaffolding tool or framework?

Comment: We're starting from scratch. We use predefined user permissions to track access across the site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add role based authorization to your site.

In the user table, add a user type field which tells us if the user is a admin or a customer.

Make sure this field is correctly set when a admin user registers, versus a customer.

Across your application, you will need to have authorization based code.

In the backend express code, add a middleware to all the modules that need to be protected. This will be a hasAuthorization function that checks the logged in user type and allows the request to pass through or returns a unauthorized response. Below is an example of adding a hasAuthorization middleware to the express route:

```
    app.route('/emails/:emailId')
    .put(users.requiresLogin, emails.hasAuthorization, emails.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, emails.hasAuthorization, emails.delete);
```

In the front end angular code, show and hide links or menu options based on the user type. If you have implemented Authentication, you probably already have an Authentication service that logs in user and returns the user details. Store the returned user as a scope property. Check this user type to show and hide menus and links. Use it also to load different pages or templates as you need.

If you think your application could have more than the admin and customer roles in future, it might need to be more elaborate with a collection defining the list of modules that each role has access to. The hasAuthorization function could be passed a module name that it can check if the user is in a role that has access to it.

If your admin application looks and behaves drastically different than the customer site, you can create a separate application for it. They will still share the database so you will need to make sure that the backend authorization is in place so that users cannot manipulate the restful apis to get into admin modules.